# Android ListView Layout inflater

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, layout-inflater

We are working with list views in college at the moment. My lecturer gave us a simple application that displays mail messages in a list and when the user selects one it displays the content of the message in a new activity. I understand pretty much all of what is going on but there are a few grey areas I want to clear up!

Basically I am wondering what this section of code does?

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.inbox_row, null);
    }
```

This method is located within a class that extends ArrayAdapter. Am I right in thinking that it is some form of recycling? for when views go on and off the screen?....

Any help is much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70. Have a look at the link. Your question is probably answered.

Comment: If you have three items in your list, and there is space on the screen for three rows in your ListView, getView() will be called three times with a null View to create those three rows. You cannot recycle a row that is presently in use.

Comment: Ok I see, and is the layout inflater basically putting the views onto the list where it says v = vi.inflate(.layout.inbox_row, null)?

Comment: Have a look at the video in the link. That should help you understanding listview better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's exactly what you said, a form of recycling.

Inflating a layout takes a lot of memory and a lot of time, so for the efficiency sake, the system passes to you that just went off the screen and you can simply update its text and images and give them back to the UI.

So for example, if your list view is showing 6 items on its list (due to the height of it), it will only inflate 6 items and during scroll it just keeps recycling them.

there's some extra optimisations tricks that you should use and I'm sure that the video link that the commenter posted will explain them.

**edit**

that example is an ArrayAdapter of Store items, but you can make it to whatever you need.
the adapter does the match and separation layer between UI and data.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null)
    convertView = newView();

    // Store is the type of this ArrayAdapter
    Store store = getItem(position);
    Holder h = (Holder) convertView.getTag();

    // And here I get the data and address them to the UI
    // as you can see, if the convertView is not null,
    // I'm not creating a new one, I'm just changing text, images, etc
    h.storeName.setText(store.getStoreName());
    h.address.setText(store.getAddressLine1());
    h.postcode.setText(store.getPostCode());
    h.distance.setText(store.getDistance());

    return convertView;
}

// I like to separate in a different method when the convertView is null
// but that's me being organisation obsessive
// but it also makes easy to see which methods are only being called the 1st time
private View newView() {
    LayoutInflater inf = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View v = inf.inflate(R.layout.map_result_list, null);
    Holder h = new Holder();
    // here we store that holder inside the view itself
    v.setTag(h);

    // and only call those findById on this first start
    h.storeName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtLine1);
    h.address = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtLine2);
    h.postcode = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtLine3);
    h.distance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtDistance);

    return v;
}

// this class is here just to hold reference to the UI elements
// findViewById is a lengthy operation so this is one of the optimisations
private class Holder {
    TextView storeName;
    TextView address;
    TextView postcode;
    TextView distance;
}
```

Comment: I get what your saying. But when it is called 6 times and v no longer == null what happens? Or is there more going on behind the scenes, listening for a view to go of the screen and freeing up a v by setting it == to null?

Comment: no no... I suggest you to watch the video the guy commented and give me a minute I'll update my answer with a sample code of a full proper ArrayAdapter implementation

Comment: as you see on the example, the v returned is exactly the same one you inflated before, and then on your code you'll just re-purpose it to be the view on the other position.